# Enhance jQuery markdown code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, markdown

I am working on a jQuery markdown script. It makes words wrapped in double asterisks in bold (just like the editor here.

Also, if you start your sentence with a `>` symbol:

```
> Hello World.
```

It wraps the sentence into blockquote. It works great, see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/pezbdt2h/

Now, I want to improve this part of the code so that **if the sentence starts with a P tag and has an great than symbol at the beginning**, then it should wrap the sentence into blockquote as well:

```
<p>> Hello World.
```

Here is the code:

```
function markdown(markdownableOrg) {

    var bold = /\*\*(\S(.*?\S)?)\*\*/gm;

var dataArray=markdownableOrg.split("\n");
    var data=[];
for(var i=0;i<dataArray.length;i++)
{
     var    markdownable =dataArray[i];
      markdownable = markdownable.replace(bold, '<span style="font-weight:bold">$1</span>');
    if (markdownable.indexOf("&gt;") == 0) {
        markdownable = markdownable.replace("&gt;", "<blockquote>");
        markdownable += "</blockquote>";
    }
    data.push(markdownable)
}

    return data.join("\n");
}
```

How do I enhance the code so that it detects `<p>>` as well and wraps it into blockquote? I suppose an AND/OR type of question within the code.

Comment: The big question is why are you reinventing the wheel? i.e. how is your wheel going to be different/better?

Comment: @amphetamachine Are you asking why I am not making this server-side? It is for a personal project of mine and not relevant to the question at hand :)

Comment: I'm asking why you're reinventing [this wheel](https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js). [Or this one](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/wiki/PageDown).

Comment: @amphetamachine Oh right. Because I do not need to implement all the functions of those scripts. Only looking for bold/blockquote. Secondly, I am trying to improve my coding abilities which are limited. Can we please get back to the actual question? :)

Comment: If your use case is really limited you might get away with regexs. But please be aware that generally, that's no way to write a parser.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the same function for innerHTML on each DOM element?

```
 jQuery('.revision_content *').each(function() {
    var markdownable = jQuery(this).html(),
        revision_content = markdown(markdownable);

    jQuery(this).html(revision_content);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pezbdt2h/)